# Does a sparse Javascript array with whole number keys remain sorted by key?

Tags: javascript

For example:

```
var a = [];
a[5] = 'five';
a[2] = 'two';
a[11] = 'eleven';
a[210] = 'two-ten';
a[4] = 'four';
a[56] = 'fifty-six';
a[1] = 'one';
a[39] = 'thirty-nine';

for( var i in a ) {
    if( a.hasOwnProperty(i) ) {
        console.log(i+":"+a[i]);
    }
}
```

Results in the following (for a few browsers I have handy to test.)

```
1:one
2:two
4:four
5:five
11:eleven
39:thirty-nine
56:fifty-six
210:two-ten
```

Is this standard, reliable behaviour?

Comment: I haven't got the details to hand, but I found different behaviours in some browsers when I looked at this a couple of years ago...

Comment: @Adam: Really? I haven't.

Comment: If you initialize it as an object, with curly brackets, instead of square brackets (for arrays) you may get irregular behaviors between browsers.

Comment: Arrays are always in order. always.

Answer (score 3):

They will always be in order, yes, but standards (as far as I'm aware) end up setting all of the in-between indexes as undefined.

Edit:
If you initialize it as an object, with curly braces, instead of square braces (for arrays) you may get irregular behaviors between browsers.

Comment: Correct. If the OP iterated over the array _properly_ (i.e. from `0` to `a.length` then he'd see that, if only because it's inherent). His loop ATM is a bit hacky.

Comment: I know undefined indices are created and I know that for..length would include them. What I don't know is if iterating it sparsely would always be in numeric order. That's the use case I'm interested in.

Comment: @pixelmike Yes, it will be, as long as it is in fact an array object and not a regular old object.

Answer (score 0):

ECMA-262 does not specify enumeration order.

Some browser implement them in ordered way others don't, like [V8](https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164) to save memory.

Comment: That's initialized as a regular object, not an array.

Comment: []  is an array constructor

Comment: Correct. There is no array constructor used in the link you specified. An array is, by definition, an indexed (ordered) list.

Comment: v8 keeps plain object properties in insertion order, expect for numerical indices, which it orders.